# Zikula CMS - Installation issue

Tags: apache, symfony, routes, zikula

I'm experiencing a problem installing both Zikula 1.5.9 and 2.0.13 in my Apache server under Ubuntu. Both versions are not able to find the /install directory.

I'm using an Apache 2.4 server with PHP 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 under Ubuntu, running in a local virtual machine.

As the video tutorial shows, I downloaded the most recent releases from GitHub, expanded the files (like sudo tar -xpvzf 2.0.13.tar.gz) into the web root and renamed the folder (like sudo mv 2.0/ zikula20)
Then I created a database for each version.

Calling http://myhost/zikula20/ in my browser, the response is:

Not Found
The requested URL /zikula20/install was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at myhost Port 80

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what is the `/include` directory for? this is not part of standard Zikula install

Comment: Did you download the correct file? Maybe you downloaded the 'source code' link instead of the `2.0.tar.gz` link?

Comment: Sorry, Craigh, my mistake. The correct directory is /install, as is in the server response. I modified my post. And yes, I'm sure the file I'm using is 2.0.tar.gz.

Comment: `/install` is not a *directory* it is a *route* that is located by the Symfony router. My guess is you have something configured improperly for this (e.g. see comments below about `RewriteBase` etc. This _should_ be automatically checked for you when attempting to install Zikula (like it is for Symfony). But apparently this isn't being done. I supposed you could attempt to install Symfony alone and see what happens. But you might look up answers based on *Symfony* and your given error to see if you can find hints.

Comment: for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098900/symfony-doesnt-load-a-page

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199481/routing-not-working-in-symfony-3-4

Comment: Thank you, Craigh. I'll try to install Symfony and Zikula in a clean environment and inform you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have had issues like this in the past it is because I inadvertently skipped a stepped during the installation process. It might help to go back through the installation document and make sure everything was done in the correct order. From what you posted, it looks like you meet the system requirements.

Also, check your php and apache logs. That might tell you where the process is failing. Good luck and post back here if you have any more information.

Comment: Well, there were no errors in the Apache log, but I eventually realized that the error was the absence of errors! For some reason, the server configuration was corrupted and the .htaccess file was not executed. I restored the correct Apache configuration and now Zikula works great. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: I am glad to hear you got it working. I alway suspected it was something weird in the configuration. Keep asking if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install it into a sub directory of a domain you probably need to uncomment this line in the `.htaccess` file and change it to the name of your directory (`/zikula20`):

https://github.com/zikula/core/blob/master/src/.htaccess#L15

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed the line to RewriteBase /zikula20 but, that did not solve the problem. I tried uncommenting the line #AllowOverride All, with the same result. Where could I investigate?

Comment: I have just verified I can reproduce the same problem moving Zikula 1.5 in the root, so I suppose the problem with RewriteBase is unrelated.