# Symfony 3.4 routing doesn't work in a new installation

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-3.4

I am trying to set up a brand new installation of Symfony 3.4 on my laptop. I've got the home page working. Then I followed the tutorial on Symfony's website for adding a page, which directed me to make a controller like this:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class LuckyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

which then should work. But visiting /lucky/number displays a 404 error.

I tried clearing the cache it didn't work.

I, also, tried doing `var_dump('something');` in my `/web/app.php` file to see if the request hits that file and it does, which means that it's not a problem with Apache or the .htaccess file but rather a Symfony issue.

I, also, tried googling but there isn't much on the topic.

I've, also, looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199481/routing-not-working-in-symfony-3-4) but my .htaccess file seems to work.

EDIT 2:

Here is my log:

```
[2019-07-08 16:31:51] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /lucky/number"" at /var/www/symfony-test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 139 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /lucky/number\" at /var/www/symfony-test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:139, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /var/www/symfony-test/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php:50)"} []
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Routing not working in Symfony 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199481/routing-not-working-in-symfony-3-4)

Comment: I looked at that, I have a working .htaccess file

Comment: Do you have any logs ? If you are in debug mode you should see some router logs

Comment: @Arnaud I've added my log

Comment: You can try "bin/console server:start" to test your route but you probably have something else going on.  "bin/console debug:router" might also help.  In any event, if you are just learning the framework then you really should not be using the now discontinued symfony installer.  Use the Flex approach "composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton project"

Comment: "bin/console server:start" works, interesting why it doesn't work when using Apache...

Comment: Almost certainly your cache though you did say your cleared it.  Why are your testing in production mode?  Get it working in development first.

Comment: How to change the mode?